# Axios POST data does not send in correct format to Express Server

Tags: node.js, express, axios, formidable

Hi I'm running an express server that has this `.post` routed on `/` and using `Formidable` and `express.json()` as middleware.

### Express Server

```
const formidable = require('express-formidable');
app.use(express.json());
app.use(formidable());

app.post('/test', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.fields);
})
```

### Using AJAX (No Issues)

When I send a POST request using `AJAX` like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'http://localhost:3000/test',
  type: "POST",
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    "file" : "background.js"
  },
  success: async function (response) {
  }
})
```

The server outputs:

```
{ file: 'background.js' }
```

### The Problem

However, when I send the same POST request using `AXIOS`

```
var fUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/test';
var fHeader = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.88 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
};
var req = await axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: fUrl,
    withCredentials: true,
    data: {"file" : 'background.js'},
    headers: fHeader
});
```

The server ouputs in the wrong format:

```
{ '{"file":"background.js"}': '' }
```

I suspect that the issue may be because of the `content-type` header, however when i change it to `application/json`, the request doesn't complete/timeout and `awaits` for an apparently infinite amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(formidable());
```

never use both at the same time.

Also that is not the way to send a file, but that would be another Q&A